# Accessing observable variable before and after setting a value is not working

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

I have 2 variables declared as mtn and atn whose values get populated based on the API ajax response.

Now, I am assigning mtn and atn variables with a value returned from API response and in my case since mtn is coming as null whereas atn is having a 10 digit number. So I am assigning atn1, atn2, atn3 with substring of atn whereas mtn1, mtn2 and mtn3 is untouched as you can see from below code snippet.

```
var ViewModel = {
mtn: null,
atn: null,
mtn1: ko.observable(null),
mtn2: ko.observable(null),
mtn3: ko.observable(null),
atn1: ko.observable(null),
atn2: ko.observable(null),
atn3: ko.observable(null)
}
// Ajax API call happens and assigns ViewModel.mtn and ViewModel.atn
if (ViewModel.mtn != null && ViewModel.mtn.length == 10) { //This condition is not true because ViewModel.mtn is coming as null in case and so mtn1, mtn2 and mtn3 observables are untouched
ViewModel.mtn1 = ViewModel.mtn.substring(0, 3);
ViewModel.mtn2 = ViewModel.mtn.substring(3, 6);
ViewModel.mtn3 = ViewModel.mtn.substring(6, 10);
}
if (ViewModel.atn != null && ViewModel.atn.length == 10) {
ViewModel.atn1 = ViewModel.atn.substring(0, 3);
ViewModel.atn2 = ViewModel.atn.substring(3, 6);
ViewModel.atn3 = ViewModel.atn.substring(6, 10);
}
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);

// Click event happens from View and Business logic UI validations take place below
processClick: function() {
     .var strmtn = ViewModel.mtn1 + ViewModel.mtn2 + ViewModel.mtn3; // This is not working and throwing error and only ViewModel.mtn1() is working
      var stratn = ViewModel.atn1 + ViewModel.atn2 + ViewModel.atn3; // This is working fine but ViewModel.atn1() is not working.
```

I believe the reason for the method of accessing atn1 as ViewModel.atn1 is working whereas method of accessing mtn1 as ViewModel.mtn1 is not working is because of re-assignment of observable for atn1 whereas mtn1 is not touched.

So how do I know which method of access to invoke an observable value since I don't know if my observables were touched or not ? :(

P.S: This issue is occuring in Knockout 3.x version which I am using. I just added 2.x versions as well.

Comment: That's not how you set or get a value of an observable. After the line `ViewModel.mtn1 = ViewModel.mtn.substring(0, 3)`, `mtn1` is no longer an observable, it's a regular string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An observable is a getter-setter function. To set its contents, you do

```
ViewModel.mtn1(ViewModel.mtn.substring(0, 3));
```

To get its contents, you do

```
value = ViewModel.mtn1();
```